# Detect Siri spinning

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, uitextfield, siri

Clearing UITextfield when siri is spinning is crashing the app.
Also while checking the length of uitextfield when siri is spinning is always greater than zero. 
Can someone guide how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.